# concatenate in sql or t-sql from previous row

Tags: sql, t-sql, concatenation

I have got some real trouble here. I have the following data in a table.

```
(Input)  (Output) (Status)
YELLOW   YELLOW   YELLO-YELLOW     - because there is no previous row. Please watch the next
Red       GREEN   YELLOW,RED-YELLOW-GREEN
```

.. basically I need a stored procedure or a way to get the previous row from the table record and add it to the next one. I have been struggling to do it the last few days without any luck. Please help. Thank you.

I have this so far:

```
select input, output, concat(input,output) as status from Status
```

However I am not able to concatenate the existing row. In my example if Input is YELLOW and Output is YELLOw I get the first row for the Status field YELLOW-YELLOW. But in the next record if I have RED for input and GREEN for the Output in this case I should have for Status YELLOW,RED - YELLOW,GREEN.

Basically I need to find a way to get the previus record for the Input field and Output field and add it to the next record.

Comment: Show us [what you have tried](http://www.whatyouhavetried.com). We don't write code for people.

Comment: Hi @njk. Thanks for your quick reply. I have this so far select input, output, concat(input,output) as status from Status. However I am able to concatenate the existing row. In my example if Input is YELLOW and Output is YELLOw I get the first row for the Status field YELLOW-YELLOW. But in the next record if I have RED for input and GREEN for the Output in this case I should have for Status YELLOW,RED - YELLOW,GREEN. Basically I need to find a way to get the previus record for the Input field and Output field and add it to the next record. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit your original question, explaining it as you have in your comment. Also you MUST have a column that actually indicates what is the previous record, i.e. a row number or incrementing column. There is no concept of 'previous record' in a database without a column telling what order the records are in.

Comment: Your explanation makes no sense. What will the next row look like? Which value goes where? It's a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Got to be honest, not 100% sure what you're looking for with your question.  But if I'm understanding correctly, you would like to to get the input/output from the previous row and add it to the status of the current row?

Something like this should help get you started depending on your RDBMS -- this is specific to SQL Server:

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS row
   FROM yourTable
)
SELECT 
  t1.input, 
  t1.output, 
  CASE 
    WHEN t2.input IS NULL
      THEN t1.input + '-' + t1.output
    ELSE 
      t2.input + ',' + t1.input + '-' + t2.output + ',' + t1.output
  END status
FROM cte t1
  LEFT JOIN cte t2 ON t1.row = t2.row+1
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c677b/2) for testing.

Good luck.